# Find the similarity between a string input and a string column of a Data Frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, nlp, fuzzywuzzy

I have a pandas data frame with two columns containing strings, like below:

```
Col-1                 Col-2
Animal                have an apple
Fruit                 tiger safari
Veg                   Vegetable Market
Flower                Garden
```

From this i have to create a function which takes a string as argument.

This function then checks the `fuzziwuzzy` similarity between the input string and the elements of `Col-2` and outputs the elements of `Col-1` and `Col-2` corresponding of the highest computed similarity.

For instance suppose input string is `Gardening Hobby`, here it will check similarity with all the elements of `df['Col-2']`. The function finds this ways that `Garden` as the highest similarity with `Gardening Hobby` with a score of 90. Then Expected output is:

```
I/P               O/P
Gardening Hobby   Garden(60),Flower
```

Comment: Your problem isn't really clear. What are the `count` you are talking about? Why does the string `BOTH` should throw `Error in Message`? What kind of similarity are you trying to compute? What do you do with the similarity computed between your input string and elements of `Col-2`? How do you get `Garden(60),Flower` as output in your example? Please make your issue clearer if you want an answer.

Comment: @ysearka..I have edited my question.. Hope it is fine now.

Comment: Not just yet, in your example you check the similarity between your input string and elements of `df['Col-2']`, but in your previous paragraph you say that you also need to compute the similarity with the first column? And what is the `60` in your output? The similarity score? If so, how is it computed?

Comment: @ysearka..60 is the similarity score. We have to compute  using fuzzywuzzy logic.I have not computed , just an example. I have to check the similarity of the input string with the Col-2 value only.

Comment: The solution of gyx-hh seems to be working, please consider accepting it if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach using the `fuzzywuzzy` library - [tutorial](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/fuzzing-matching-in-pandas-with-fuzzywuzzy/)

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

search_str = 'Gardening Hobby'
# extract the best match of search_str in df['Col-2']
best_match = process.extractOne(search_str, df['Col-2'])
print(best_match)  # output: ('Garden', 90, 3)  (match,score,index)

# get results for 'Col-1' using the index
res = df.iloc[best_match[2]]['Col-1']
print(res)  # output: 'Flower'

# construct the output string as you wish
'%s(%d), %s' % (best_match[0], best_match[1], res)

# output: 'Garden(90), Flower'
```